# Selecting rows based upon a search string or any of its synonyms

Tags: mysql

I need some help please...

I have 2 tables, one contains a description field which is entered freehand by the user, the second table is made up of 2 columns, the first is a group name and the second is a list of synonyms. So, for example, I might have three rows in the synonyms table in a group called A that contains the synonyms 'Leaflet', 'Brochure', 'Hand Bill'.

What I need to do is return all rows from the first table where the ItemDescription column contains any of the synonyms of the query variable which might be 'Leaflet'.

So this should give me all of the rows that contain anywhere in the long description field the words 'Leaflet', 'Brochure' or 'Hand Bill'.

I have been able to do this only where the ItemDescription field contains only actual words being looked for, in reality this os a long wordy column that may contain 50 or 60 words any one of which may be one of the search word or any of its synonyms.

All help gratefully received as always.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to use `LIKE` or `RLIKE` to match the description column. In this case, you want to match a number of alternatives, so I'll just show an example.

Let us assume that we have this table containing synonyms. Note that we have added the word itself as a synonym:

```
+---------+-----------+
| word    | synonym   |
+---------+-----------+
| leaflet | leaflet   |
| leaflet | brochure  |
| leaflet | hand bill |
| skin    | skin      |
| skin    | leather   |
| skin    | hide      |
+---------+-----------+
```

You don't give an example table, so I invented one called `items`:

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
| item_id | brief             | description                       |
+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
|       1 | Diamond           | This brochure is glossy and shiny |
|       2 | Halloween Special | A leaflet for the Halloween       |
|       3 | Pumpkin           | This is just a Halloween pumpkin  |
+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Now, we assume that you want to look for all rows containing one of the synonyms of 'leaflet' in the description. The following query does the job:

```
SELECT * FROM items
 WHERE description RLIKE (
    SELECT
       CONCAT('.*(', GROUP_CONCAT(synonym SEPARATOR '|'), ').*')
      FROM synonyms
     WHERE word = 'leaflet'
     GROUP BY word
  );
```

The inner select create a regular expression matching one of the synonyms, and the outer select applies this regular expression to the `description` column of our `items` table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.  I have found an answer to my SQL needs:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MainTable a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    (
                Select concat('%',Synonym,'%') As cond
                From synonyms
                Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%'
                OR ListRef = (  Select ListRef 
                                From synonyms
                                Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%')
                ) с
        WHERE   a.Description LIKE cond
        )
OR ItemDescription Like '%SearchString%'
```

Without the final OR I was only returning rows where something existed in the synonyms table for my search string, with the OR it also returns all straight matches not found through synonyms.